# Convergence in distribution to a Poisson

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

We have encountered the following problem that we think that should be true. Let $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ a sequence of random variables which we know that $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ tends to infinity.

The question is the following: can we assure that the sequence does *NOT* converge in distribution to a Poisson?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It's easy to construct a sequence $Y_n$ with $Y_n \to 0$ a.s. but $E Y_n \to +\infty$. (You can even have $E Y_n \equiv +\infty$ if you wish.) Now let $X$ be a fixed Poisson random variable and $X_n = X + Y_n$.

Answer (score 2):

As Nate Eldridge noted, the answer is no.  For a positive result, you need some extra condition.  Suppose e.g. the variances $\text{Var}(X_n) < c (E X_n)^2$ for $n$ sufficiently large, with some constant $c \in (0,1)$.
Then  $X_n$ can't converge in distribution.